# Using mockito when thenReturn with a new object

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I've got the following line of code in my implementation:

```
myService.getTypes(new TypeRequest(myList.stream().map(Object::toString)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())))
```

and I tried to mock the above in my test class as follows:

```
when(myService.getTypes(new TypeRequest(Lists.newArrayList("15", "16"))))
                .thenReturn(Lists.newArrayList(type1, type2));
when(myService.getTypes(new TypeRequest(Lists.newArrayList("25", "26"))))
                .thenReturn(Lists.newArrayList(type3, type4));
```

But when I debug the test code, I can see that `myService.getTypes` is returning an empty list. What could be the problem?

Also, is there a way to use args to simplify the above mocking? All I found was using `args` passed into the method, not the args of args passed into the method.

Comment: You probably need to use the `ArgumentMatcher` to inspect and compare the argument passed to the method because the actual argument is not the same from the Mockito's point-of-view.  See https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
when(myService.getTypes(any(TypeRequest.class)))
    .thenAnswer(invocationOnMock -> {
        TypeRequest r = invocationOnMock.getArgument(0);
        //if r contains "15"
            return Lists.newArrayList(type1, type2);
        } else {
            return Lists.newArrayList(type3, type2);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, it uses `equals()` of the input argument to check if it is matched with any stubbed parameters. Most probably you do not implement  `TypeRequest` 's `equals()` , so no stubbed parameters are matched and hence it returns the default result for the unstubbed invocation which is an empty list.

If you do not want to implement `equals()` for `TypeRequest` , the correct way is to use `argThat()` to define a `ArgumentMatcher` for the input argument :

```java
@Test
public void someTest(){
    
    when(myService.getTypes(argThat(requestListContainAll(Lists.newArrayList("15", "16")))))
                  .thenReturn(Lists.newArrayList(type1, type2));
    myService.getTypes(Lists.newArrayList("15", "16"))); //it should return the above stubbed value
}


private ArgumentMatcher<TypeRequest> requestListContainAll(List<String> list){
    return arg-> arg.getList().containsAll(list);
}
```